# J-Link connection to Cortex-A53 (Raspberry PI3b+)

Tags: arm, jtag

I've got a JTAG (J-Link more precisely) related problem. 
I'm trying to connect by J-Link to raspberry pi 3b+ (bare-metal).
The probe finds the CPU and reads coresight ROM table, but there are missing information about Cross Trigger Interface (CTI). The units are available in the CPU according to ARM documentation.
There is a possibility to write a special script for J-Link, to set up CPU but documentation is poor and I do not know how to do it.

It there anyone who had or met with similar problem? Any advice how to run it?

Below is output from run of JLinkExe with attempt to connect:

```
./JLinkExe
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V6.52c Command Line Version

JLinkARM.dll V6.52c (DLL compiled Oct 11 2019 15:44:50)

Command line: -if jtag -device Cortex-A53 -endian little -speed auto -port 2331 -swoport 2332 -telnetport 2333 -vd -ir -localhostonly 1 -singlerun -strict -timeout 0 -nogui -jlinkscriptfile /home/piotr/rpi.JLinkScript
-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file:                  none
GDB Server Listening port:     2331
SWO raw output listening port: 2332
Terminal I/O port:             2333
Accept remote connection:      localhost only
Generate logfile:              off
Verify download:               on
Init regs on start:            on
Silent mode:                   off
Single run mode:               on
Target connection timeout:     0 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface:         USB
J-Link script:                 /home/piotr/rpi.JLinkScript
J-Link settings file:          none
------Target related settings------
Target device:                 Cortex-A53
Target interface:              JTAG
Target interface speed:        auto
Target endian:                 little

Connecting to J-Link...
J-Link is connected.
Firmware: J-Link V10 compiled Oct  8 2019 14:57:57
Hardware: V10.10
S/N: 260111336
OEM: SEGGER-EDU
Feature(s): FlashBP, GDB
Checking target voltage...
Target voltage: 3.09 V
Listening on TCP/IP port 2331
Connecting to target...ERROR: CTI connected to core not found. Debugging not possible

ERROR: CTI connected to core not found. Debugging not possible

ERROR: Could not connect to target.
Target connection failed. GDBServer will be closed...Restoring target state and closing J-Link connection...
Shutting down...
Could not connect to target.
Please check power, connection and settings. piotr  /  opt  JLink  ./JLinkExe 
SEGGER J-Link Commander V6.52c (Compiled Oct 11 2019 15:44:58)
DLL version V6.52c, compiled Oct 11 2019 15:44:50

Connecting to J-Link via USB...O.K.
Firmware: J-Link V10 compiled Oct  8 2019 14:57:57
Hardware version: V10.10
S/N: 260111336
License(s): FlashBP, GDB
OEM: SEGGER-EDU
VTref=3.085V


Type "connect" to establish a target connection, '?' for help
J-Link>connect
Please specify device / core. <Default>: CORTEX-A53
Type '?' for selection dialog
Device>
Please specify target interface:
  J) JTAG (Default)
  S) SWD
  T) cJTAG
TIF>J
Device position in JTAG chain (IRPre,DRPre) <Default>: -1,-1 => Auto-detect
JTAGConf>
Specify target interface speed [kHz]. <Default>: 4000 kHz
Speed>
Device "CORTEX-A53" selected.


Connecting to target via JTAG
TotalIRLen = 4, IRPrint = 0x01
JTAG chain detection found 1 devices:
 #0 Id: 0x4BA00477, IRLen: 04, CoreSight JTAG-DP
Scanning AP map
AP scan stopped (required AP found)
AP[0]: APB-AP
Scanning ROMTbl @ 0x80000000
[0]Comp[0] @ 0x80010000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[1] @ 0x80011000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[2] @ 0x80012000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[3] @ 0x80013000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[4] @ 0x80014000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[5] @ 0x80015000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[6] @ 0x80016000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[7] @ 0x80017000: PMU-A53
End of ROM table
TotalIRLen = 4, IRPrint = 0x01
JTAG chain detection found 1 devices:
 #0 Id: 0x4BA00477, IRLen: 04, CoreSight JTAG-DP
Scanning AP map
AP scan stopped (required AP found)
AP[0]: APB-AP
Scanning ROMTbl @ 0x80000000
[0]Comp[0] @ 0x80010000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[1] @ 0x80011000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[2] @ 0x80012000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[3] @ 0x80013000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[4] @ 0x80014000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[5] @ 0x80015000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[6] @ 0x80016000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[7] @ 0x80017000: PMU-A53
End of ROM table

****** Error: CTI connected to core not found. Debugging not possible

TotalIRLen = 4, IRPrint = 0x01
JTAG chain detection found 1 devices:
 #0 Id: 0x4BA00477, IRLen: 04, CoreSight JTAG-DP
Scanning AP map
AP scan stopped (required AP found)
AP[0]: APB-AP
Scanning ROMTbl @ 0x80000000
[0]Comp[0] @ 0x80010000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[1] @ 0x80011000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[2] @ 0x80012000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[3] @ 0x80013000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[4] @ 0x80014000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[5] @ 0x80015000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[6] @ 0x80016000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[7] @ 0x80017000: PMU-A53
End of ROM table
TotalIRLen = 4, IRPrint = 0x01
JTAG chain detection found 1 devices:
 #0 Id: 0x4BA00477, IRLen: 04, CoreSight JTAG-DP
Scanning AP map
AP scan stopped (required AP found)
AP[0]: APB-AP
Scanning ROMTbl @ 0x80000000
[0]Comp[0] @ 0x80010000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[1] @ 0x80011000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[2] @ 0x80012000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[3] @ 0x80013000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[4] @ 0x80014000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[5] @ 0x80015000: PMU-A53
[0]Comp[6] @ 0x80016000: Cortex-A53
[0]Comp[7] @ 0x80017000: PMU-A53
End of ROM table

****** Error: CTI connected to core not found. Debugging not possible

Cannot connect to target.
```

Comment: I know that it's been a couple of years since this post. Did you ever manage to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You may find some of the information you need in this (detailed) [article](https://metebalci.com/blog/bare-metal-raspberry-pi-3b-jtag/).
The (DBG/)CTI addresses you are looking for would then be:

```
set DBGBASE {0x80010000 0x80012000 0x80014000 0x80016000}
set CTIBASE {0x80018000 0x80019000 0x8001a000 0x8001b000}
```

Please note that you can test using OpenOCD, since it does support your J-Link EDU, by using the `tcl/interface/jlink.cfg` definition file, prior to resume your testing with J-Link commander.
You should use the trunk version of OpenOCD, since 0.10 does not support Armv8 form what I understand. The git repository is located here: git://repo.or.cz/openocd.git

Regarding the J-Link-specific script, you may search on the Segger support forum archives now that you know the CTI addresses, the information you are looking for may be available there. If not, just ask for help on the forum.

Update: you already asked for support on the forum I guess.

From the [manual](https://www.segger.com/downloads/jlink/UM08001), page 218,  you may just need to set `CORESIGHT_Core-BaseAddr` in your script - there is an example [here](https://github.com/kamejoko80/my_osek/blob/master/NEO_M4_OSEK/tool/IMX6SX_WITH_JLINK_V1.0/IMX6SX_HOW_TO_DEBUG_CORE_M4.txt).

Comment: Hi there,

thank you for your answer. Yes I had asked on Segger forum. Also I know about OpenOCD and adresses. I wantend to make Segger tools running, unfortunately I didn't manage to do it, since my question here. Nevertheless thank you for your support. I've found in one sample string commang to set CTI base adress but it didn't work. Maybe I did something wrong. I'll try with smaple you have suggested to fiugre out something from there. I'll post here my findings.